# Some basic regular expressions

Tags: regex

I'm rubbish at regex - always get myself confused. I've been asked to check the following, with an alphabet of 0 and 1.

```
1] Must start with a 1 - client has put 1+0|1
2] Any number of 0s followed by any number of 1s - client has put 0*0|1
3] Any combination of 0s and 1s - client has put 0*1*
```

they don't look right to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard syntax would be:

1. `1[01]*`
2. `0*1*`
3. `[01]*`

Comment: I knew it was off! Thanks :) will mark as right once time is up!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
1: ^1[01]*  or ^1[01] if its just starting with 1 and followed by 0 or 1
2: 0*1*
3: [01]*
```